# Empty Grid in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid-php

I am trying to integrate a grid to my PHP project, JQgrid looked so easy!!
When i Integrated I was only able to see the grid, not the data in the grid!
I have just change the db settings of the sample code to work with my DB.

Debug results:

1. When I debugged with firebug I am able to see the db rows in the consolde mode of firebug.
2. Here with also pasting the logs of jqGrid.log
3. It also throws a warning msg "Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for '-5.0/no DST' instead in C:\Users\Karthik\Desktop\apache\htdocs\php\jqGrid.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1"

Both files resides in root directory. Some clues to troubleshoot

PHP Code"myfristgrid.php"

require_once 'jq-config.php';

// include the jqGrid Class

require_once "php/jqGrid.php";

require_once "php/jqGridPdo.php";

$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);

$grid->debug = true;

$grid->SelectCommand = 'SELECT * FROM question';

$grid->datatype = 'json';

$grid->setColModel();

$grid->setUrl('myfirstgrid.php');

$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "caption"=>"This is custom Caption",
    "rowNum"=>10,
    "sortname"=>"id",
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,50),
    ));

$grid->setColProperty("id", array("label"=>"ID", "width"=>60));

// Enjoy

$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);

$conn = null;

---

jqGrid.log

Executed 2 query(s) - 2011-01-26 22:50:28
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2011-01-26 22:50:28
            [query] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT  FROM question
            [data] => 
            [types] => 
            [fields] => 
            [primary] => 
            [input] => 
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 2011-01-26 22:50:28
        [query] => SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 0, 10
        [data] => 
        [types] => 
        [fields] => 
        [primary] => 
        [input] => 
    )
```

)

---

Comment: Please post the code u used to generate the jqgrid.
It will be helpful to help u with the prob.

Answer (score 0):

You can't properly use **setColProperty** in the jqGrid.